# React Native Navigation Issue giving error after splash screen

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am trying to load my login form after the splash screen but it is giving an error as

**Error: Looks like you have nested a 'NavigationContainer' inside another. Normally you need only one container at the root of the app, so this was probably an error. If this was intentional, pass 'independent={true}' explicitly. Note that this will make the child navigators disconnected from the parent and you won't be able to navigate between them.**

[my app.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LxAZE.png)

Comment: What is inside LoginForm? Are you defining a NavigationStack there as well??

Comment: You have multiple `NavigationContainer` in your navigator?

Comment: yes @Satheesh, there was NavigationContainer inside. I removed it and it's working now. Thanks :)

Comment: @AbhishekBankar Please accept my answer if it helped you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If LoginForm has a separate NavigationStack configured inside it this issue will occur, please try after removing it.

Answer (score 2):

As far as my understanding is concerned. I can see some place of improvements, and one of them would be:

- Using `replace()` correctly with the help of [StackActions reference](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-actions/)

```js
import { StackActions } from '@react-navigation/native';

navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('Home'));
```

- Use [useEffect hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html), to perform `setTimeOut()` operation in your `SplashScreen` component

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';

useEffect(() => {
  const timer = setTimeout(() => {
    navigation.dispatch(StackActions.replace('Home'));
  }, 1500);
  return () => clearTimeout(timer);
}, []);
```

I hope, you will be good after following that in your code.